# ng-src changing with some delay on photo.src change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've an img tag with ng-src attribute applied for a master detail page.

Detail page has the image, once I switch to master and return, the previous image stays for a while until the new one takes it place.

```
<img class="media-object" ng-src="{{detail.photo}}"></div>
```

my angular code, note the image property is changed outside the $scope.

```
this.$scope.detail.photo = details[0].photo;
this.$scope.$apply();
```

though on the way back switching to master, I'm nulling everything.

```
this.$scope.detail.photo = null;
this.$scope.$apply()
```

but it's not working, when I come back again, i see the previous image until the next one takes effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://makandracards.com/makandra/29415-resolving-angular-not-updating-an-image-src-when-ng-src-is-empty

```
<img class="media-object" ng-src="{{detail.photo || '//:0'}}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing ng-src to null(or any falsy value) will not change the value of the underlying src attribute([reference](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/14b3db369edd0bb6ac6f318d66f3b422a07757f9/src/ng/directive/attrs.js#L406)).
It doesn't make sense to do so, anyway. If you want to hide the picture, just use an `ng-show`.

Comment: how ng-show can help when I change my picture and that new picture would be there already? meaning the old picture won't be there, I'm re-using the <img tag for different images